# Cross-thread operation not valid even when control accessed in progress changed event

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, visual-studio-2010

I am calling backgroundworker to do the task and changing the controls through ProgressChanged Event and it worked fine until I called the backgroundwoker from another backgroundworker. Now I am getting this Crossthread Operation exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call RunWorkerAsync, the BackgroundWorker captures the synchronization context as at that point in time, and that synchronization context is subsequently used when the ProgressChanged event fires. If you happen to call RunWorkerAsync on a thread other than the UI thread (which is what happens when you call it inside another worker's DoWork handler), the ProgressChanged event then fires on a non-UI thread. If in this situation the event handler tries accessing the UI, you get the exception you described.

You will need to either move your second call to RunWorkerAsync into the handler for the ProgressChanged/RunWorkerCompleted event of the first worker, or find another way to switch to the UI thread temporarily, i.e. using Control.Invoke or a similar method.

Comment: thanks for the theory bro, i didn't know that. I think I can make my program work with single background worker, let me try that, if that didn't work, I'll return to your advice. thanks again :)

Answer (score 2):

According to the documenation for [`BackgroundWorker.ReportProgress`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ka89zff4.aspx):

> The call to the ReportProgress method is asynchronous and returns immediately. The ProgressChanged event handler executes on the thread that created the BackgroundWorker.

So you have to create your BackgroundWorkers on the UI thread if you want to update controls in the ProgressChanged event handler directly.